# Installing Windows 10 effect on installed programs

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade

I currently got Windows 8 on my machine and would like to upgrade to windows 10.

I got several products installed on my machine, will I have to do a re-installation for each of them after the upgrade?

Also Will I lose my Office product license and other licenses on doing the upgrade?

EDIT:

The installed software I got is : 
1- Microsoft Office
2- Visual Studio 2013
3- SQL Server 2014

Comment: It totally depends on what softwares are you talking about & what compatibility they offer with windows 10.

Comment: I updated my question with example of the software I'm talking about, I would appreciate your help

Comment: You should wait until July 29th before you upgrade to Windows otherwise you won't be able to activate your installation.  All personal files, application files, and installed programs will be kept.

Comment: If the software ran on Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 it will run on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are upgrading from Windows 8 to 10, Windows will attempt to save and transfer all of your applications, settings and files:

[image]

This is by no means a guarantee that everything will transfer properly though.  It is always best advice/practise to ensure that you backup EVERYTHING before installing a new operating system.  Make sure you have backed up at least all of your documents and files to a disk, but it may also be worth doing the following before an OS upgrade:

- Backup all files
- Make a list of installed software (in case manual reinstall is required)
- Ensure you list down all email accounts you have setup in mail clients (and backup mail!)
- note down any licese codes you may need for potential reinstalls (there is free sofware out there to help with finding license keys)

While Microsoft has tried to make sure that everything that works with windows 8 will still work with 10, there is always going to be some software that won't.  Typically, better known software (office, Symantec AV, Visual studio etc) will have been tested and verified as compatible, but if your computer is anything like mine, there's a multitude of lesser known titles installed which may well not have been tested.

If you find that something you use doesn't work, there's also a new Stack Exchange site for this - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  If you need a recommendation for a replacement - they should be able to help

EDIT: In responce to your updated question - I am running Office 2013 Pro and VS 2013 with windows 10 - no problems at all.  I am running SQL 2012 though, so haven't tested 2014 (although I have just asked a friend who said he didn't have problems).  While this is not an exhaustive or definitive test - it does mean its possible.